# Celery: Accessing the Broker Connection Pool

Tags: celery, connection-pooling, amqp, kombu

I'm using Celery with an AMQP broker to call tasks, but the response needs to be passed back with a different queue architecture than Celery uses, so I want to pass the messages back using Kombu only.  I've been able to do this, but I'm creating a new connection every time.  Does Celery use a broker connection pool, and if so, how do you access it?

Answer (score 16):

It took a lot of searching because Celery's documentation is... *wonderful*... but I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177491/get-worker-id-in-celery#comment-24876893) the answer.

Celery does use a broker connection pool for calling subtasks. The celery application has a [`pool` attribute](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.pool) that you can access through `<your_app>.pool` or `celery.current_app.pool`.  You can then grab a connection from the pool using `pool.acquire()`.

Comment: I am in similar situation. Is the following code correct - http://dpaste.com/2SSJ8W0 ? I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, it's possible by using Bootsteps https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/extending.html

Let me copy-paste code from documentation (e.g. prevent 404 error in future)

```py
from celery import Celery
from celery import bootsteps
from kombu import Consumer, Exchange, Queue

my_queue = Queue('custom', Exchange('custom'), 'routing_key')

app = Celery(broker='amqp://')


class MyConsumerStep(bootsteps.ConsumerStep):

    def get_consumers(self, channel):
        return [Consumer(channel,
                         queues=[my_queue],
                         callbacks=[self.handle_message],
                         accept=['json'])]

    def handle_message(self, body, message):
        print('Received message: {0!r}'.format(body))
        message.ack()
app.steps['consumer'].add(MyConsumerStep)

def send_me_a_message(who, producer=None):
    with app.producer_or_acquire(producer) as producer:
        producer.publish(
            {'hello': who},
            serializer='json',
            exchange=my_queue.exchange,
            routing_key='routing_key',
            declare=[my_queue],
            retry=True,
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_me_a_message('world!')
```